# Arrays from method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, import

I have a method `MethodA` at class `A` which returns an Array with `10` elements. 
I am calling the `MethodA` from class `B` and I want somehow to store the array in class `B`. IS there any way I could do this ? 
I am using `Java`.

Comment: To answer your question the way it is asked YES ...

Comment: Yes, assign it to an array variable.

Comment: It looks like I managed to do it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The simplest way would be to call the method inside classB and set the return value to an array field.

A different method is to have a set method in classB. For the parameter value you'd pass in the return value for methodA.